# Cannot ssh to Google Cloud VM Instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I created a google compute engine VM instance from a snapshot but I could not SSH into the instance. Got a message below saying

> We are unable to connect to the VM on port 22

Upon looking at the serial console logs, it seems stuck at login for localhost:

```
Debian GNU/Linux 8 localhost ttyS0

localhost login:
```

Comment: It's not stuck, it's waiting for you to enter login and password. If you don't have user and password to login, shutdown your VM and set a startup script by adding at the section Custom metadata key startup-script and value: `useradd --groups google_sudoers tempuser` and at the next line `echo "tempuser:password" | chpasswd`, and then start your VM. [Here](https://medium.com/google-cloud/resolving-getting-locked-out-of-a-compute-engine-85800251890b) you can find an example.

Comment: @JohnHanley yup Google Cloud Firewall allows port 22

Comment: @Stanley Please have a look at the documentation [Troubleshooting SSH](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh). Have you tried to follow the instructions?

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza yup ive checked all of that ... still no progress

Comment: @Stanley Have you tried to follow [this example](https://medium.com/google-cloud/resolving-getting-locked-out-of-a-compute-engine-85800251890b) and add temporary login and password to connect to the VM instance?

Comment: @Stanley Please collect logs. Go to `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> click on `NAME_OF_YOUR_VM` -> at the VM instance details find section `Logs` and click on `Serial port 1 (console)`. Reboot your VM instance again. Check full boot log for any errors or/and warnings and share it via [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/).

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza ive tried that solution but it doesn't work ... here's a pastebin of the logs https://pastebin.com/g8VuDYS1 on startup

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza here's another link https://pastebin.com/f9fS6HSj

Comment: @Stanley The log looks good on the first glance. Please provide more details about your use case, VM configuration and machine-type. Do you have same issue with entering the VM via Console?

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza yup it is the same issue ... used an older snapshot to create the instance and it works ... could be an issue with snapshot corruption..

Comment: Could you post an answer to make your solution more visible for other community members?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was confirmed by *@Stanley* at the comment section, this issue was be an issue related to snapshot corruption.

If you have similar issues you can follow the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh) or/and this [3rd party example](https://medium.com/google-cloud/resolving-getting-locked-out-of-a-compute-engine-85800251890b) to troubleshoot your VM instance via serial console. In addition, some step by step guidance you can find in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65320654/12428794).